# How to replace elements in a list using dictionary lookup (list as values in dict)

Tags: python, list, dictionary

With my code, I would like to return the key for every value in a list of values of a dict.
For the following code, I get the `category` list returned which is longer than my `creditaccounts` list.
The desired result is:

```
category = ['supermarket', 'supermarket', 'unknown', 'self', 'unknown']
```

I struggle with the loop and the 'unknown' element.

```
creditaccounts = ['ALBERT HEIJN 1654 ROTTERDAM NLD', 'Jumbo 199730 TILBURG NLD','10-04-14 22:38 GELDAUTOMAAT', 'ING Bank', 'Desposit']

self = ['ING Bank', 'Van Bonusrenterekening']
bank = ['Kosten OranjePakket']
supermarket = ['ALBERT HEIJN 1654 ROTTERDAM NLD', 
                'Jumbo 199730 TILBURG NLD', 'Albert Heijn 1617', 
                'Jumbo Rotterdam ROTTERDAM NLD',
                'DIRK VDBROEK FIL4014 ROTTERDAM']

dict_cat = {'self' : self
            ,'bank' : bank
            , 'supermarket': supermarket}

category = []

for creditaccount in creditaccounts:
    for cat, val in dict_cat.items():
        if creditaccount in val:
            category.append(cat)
        else:
            category.append('unknown')
            
category
```

Answer (score 1):

In your inner loop you have an if-else statement and in the else you are appending **"unknown"** to your list. This causes **"unknown"** to be appended each iteration if condition does not match.
Try breaking out of the loop and an else:

```
creditaccounts = ['ALBERT HEIJN 1654 ROTTERDAM NLD', 'Jumbo 199730 TILBURG NLD','10-04-14 22:38 GELDAUTOMAAT', 'ING Bank', 'Desposit']

self = ['ING Bank', 'Van Bonusrenterekening']
bank = ['Kosten OranjePakket']
supermarket = ['ALBERT HEIJN 1654 ROTTERDAM NLD', 
                'Jumbo 199730 TILBURG NLD', 'Albert Heijn 1617', 
                'Jumbo Rotterdam ROTTERDAM NLD',
                'DIRK VDBROEK FIL4014 ROTTERDAM']

dict_cat = {'self' : self
            ,'bank' : bank
            , 'supermarket': supermarket}

category = []

for creditaccount in creditaccounts:
    for cat, val in dict_cat.items():
        if creditaccount in val:
            category.append(cat)
            break
    else:
        category.append('unknown')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. or you can run this code to achieve your goal.

```
creditaccounts = ['ALBERT HEIJN 1654 ROTTERDAM NLD', 'Jumbo 199730 TILBURG NLD','10-04-14 22:38 GELDAUTOMAAT', 'ING Bank', 'Desposit']

self = ['ING Bank', 'Van Bonusrenterekening']
bank = ['Kosten OranjePakket']
supermarket = ['ALBERT HEIJN 1654 ROTTERDAM NLD', 
                'Jumbo 199730 TILBURG NLD', 'Albert Heijn 1617', 
                'Jumbo Rotterdam ROTTERDAM NLD',
                'DIRK VDBROEK FIL4014 ROTTERDAM']

dict_cat = {'self' : self
            ,'bank' : bank
            , 'supermarket': supermarket}

category = []
for creditaccount in creditaccounts:
    node = False
    for k, v in dict_cat.items():
        if creditaccount in v:
            category.append(k)
            node = True
    if node == False:
        category.append('unknown')
    
            
category
```

Comment: when creditaccount in dict_cat,set the code true,and category will not append 'unknown' to itself space

Answer (score 0):

I think now it should work now,

**Code Syntax**

```
for cat in dict_cat.keys():
    for creditaccount in creditaccounts:
        if creditaccount in dict_cat[cat]:
            category.append(cat)
        else:
            category.append('unknown')
```

**Explanation**

What you're looking for is to check `creditaccounts` values in each `list` of the `dict_cat`.

If the value found append 'the dict key of this list', else append 'unknown',

**Output**

```
['unknown', 'unknown', 'unknown', 'self', 'unknown', 'unknown', 
'unknown', 'unknown', 'unknown', 'unknown', 'supermarket', 
'supermarket', 'unknown', 'unknown', 'unknown']

[Program finished]
```

> *According to this results,*

```
self [list]: only element[3] found into the `creditsaccounts`.

Bank [list]: no value matched with the `creditsaccounts` list, so the whole values appeneded as 'unknown'.

supermarket [list]: its elements -> element[0], element[1].
```